# How To Designate Adjuster on Order Only

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, ordering, adjusters

Registering like so and all is well.

```
Event::on(
   OrderAdjustments::class,
   OrderAdjustments::EVENT_REGISTER_ORDER_ADJUSTERS,
   function(RegisterComponentTypesEvent $event) {
         $event->types[] = Freebie::class;
   }
 );
```

Per the docs (bolds mine):

> Each of those models may be applied to the order **or** one of its line
> items.
>
> An adjustment model always belongs to an order, but can **optionally**
> belong to a line item.

We've set up according to this [example here][1] which demonstrates looping through line items and adding the adjuster to each item. All good so far.

*But how might we add an adjuster to only the order?*

If we take the adjustment code out of the loop )as in the example linked above) and leave off the `$adjustment->setLineItem($item);`, the model does not appear in `cart.adjustments` nor `cart.orderAdjustments`

```
Craft CMS 3.7.50 [PRO]
Commerce 3.4.15 [PRO]


  [1]: https://craftcms.com/docs/commerce/3.x/extend/adjusters.html#designating-an-order-and-line-item
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

```
use craft\commerce\models\OrderAdjustment;

$adjustment = new OrderAdjustment();

$adjustment->setOrder($order); // $order - craft\commerce\elements\Order;
```

Comment: yeah no go. pretty sure `type` is also required, but yeah bare minimum: `setOrder` and `type` still does not add the adjustment to the order only.

Comment: @SteveMock That's weird

You have at the very beginning: `$adjustments = [];` ?

And in the end:

`$adjustments[] = $adjustment;`

`return $adjustments;`

Comment: that's right. the class fires `update` successfully. would it matter that this is a [sprig][https://putyourlightson.com/plugins/sprig] cart update?

Comment: I guess that yes